# useState in context provider loses data when a child components gets removed

Tags: reactjs, use-state

So I am using a context provider to give the base data to my app for example: `[{id: "a", name: "a"}]`.
Now I have a component that required the `data` portion of this object, I check if this data property is not yet there, I get it from my api, fill it and then it should not have to recall the api to get it again.

My provider:

```js
import { createContext, useState, useCallback, useMemo, useContext } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const StockContext = createContext();
export const useStock = () => useContext(StockContext);

export const StockProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [stocks, setStocks] = useState();

    const getDataFromStock = useCallback(
        async ({ id }) => {
            let method = "GET";
            let url = `${config.base_url}data/${id}`;
            try {
                const { data: response } = await axios({ method, url });
                const { succes, data, error } = response;
                let updated = stocks;
                updated.find((s) => s.id === id).data = data;
                console.log("set stocks", updated);
                setStocks(updated);
                }
                return succes;
            }
        },
        [stocks]
    );

    const value = useMemo(
        () => ({
            getDataFromStock,
            stocks,
        }),
        [getDataFromStock, stocks]
    );

    return <StockContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</StockContext.Provider>;
};
```

Note: I removed some error handling for simplicity sake.
After the function getDataFromStock with the id is called. The stocks object should look like this: `[{id: "a", name: "a", data: [{id: "c", ...}]}]`.
Now I have my component to show the details (data) from this object. It first checks if it is not already in the 'stocks' object and if not gets it.

```js
export default function StockDetailPage() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [currentStock, setCurrentStock] = useState({});
    const { stocks, getDataFromStock, testStocks } = useContext(StockContext);

    // TODO find why data keep disappearing
    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            if (!stocks.find((s) => s.id === id).data) {
                console.log("getting");
                await getDataFromStock({ id });
                // TODO Indication on loading?
            } else {
                console.log("not getting");
            }
        };
        getData();
    }, [getDataFromStock, id, stocks]);

    return (
        <div>
            Stock: {currentStock?.owner?.username}
            {stocks
                ?.find((s) => s.id === id)
                .data?.map((p) => (
                    <ProductPreview key={p.product_id} {...p} />
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now if I look at my react debugger, I see the state of the stocks has this data object, but once I navigate away from the details, this property seems to disappear. Now how could I implement this in the right way or fix the problem?

Kind regards

Comment: How do you mean "navigate away"?  Are you visiting a different URL where the context state would be lost?

Comment: I'm a little unclear where you're setting data to the provider, there's nothing setting state in the useEffect? Your context `value` is supposed to provide a setter function to update state via setStocks https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component

Comment: Yea the function getDataFromStock gets called from a nested component which then updates the stocks with the `setStocks()` function right?